# Is there a way to merge my previous questions on askubuntu.com with my registered account ( i use the same email address )

Tags: discussion, status-completed, email

Is there a way to merge my previous questions on askubuntu.com with my later registered account ( i use the same email address )?

Answer (score 7):

Okay I've done this for you.

I've merged in two unregistered accounts and you've had their questions and points allocated to your new registered account.